# Networkx Optimization, Adjacent Sets of Vertices, Contracting subgraphs

Tags: networkx, graph-theory

I have a function which returns subgraph, S, of G. I want to create a graph, H, where each connected component in S is a vertex in H, and two vertices are connected in H if there is an edge between these sets of vertices in G.

Right now, I have something that works, but creating H takes twice as long as creating S. (mostly due to the node_boundary and connected_components functions, according to cProfile) This process will be done many many times, so I'm hoping to shave of even a fraction of the time. I only really need H, so I've considering creating H without the intermediate function, but I couldn't get that to work with contraction. The issue is that the edges are supposed to be randomly chosen from G, but the edge contraction changes the names of vertices in H, and translating the name of the edge has been way to difficult for me.

Creating S:

```
def sp(G):
    nodes = list(G.nodes)
    out = nx.Graph()
    for v in nodes:
        out.add_edge(v, random.choice(list(G.neighbors(v))))
    return out
```

Creating H from S:

```
spr = sp(G)
H = nx.Graph()
bound = []

CC = list(nx.connected_components(spr))
for c in CC:
    H.add_node(CC.index(c))

for c in CC:
    bound.append(nx.node_boundary(G,c))
    for b in bound:
        inter = c.intersection(b)
        if len(inter) > 0:
            H.add_edge(CC.index(c), bound.index(b))
```

Creating H without S:

```
nodes = list(G.nodes)
edges = []
out = G.copy()
for v in nodes:
    edges.append( (v, random.choice(list(G.neighbors(v)))) )

for e in edges:
    out = nx.contracted_edge(out, e)
return out
```

Comment: Node IDs can be any hashable type. Instead of using integers that cannot keep track of their "heritage", I would use tuples. I haven't worked out the details but that should take care of your "translation" problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its usually easier to work with the adjacency matrix.  Here is a quick a dirty code snippet that will do a matrix contraction given an arbitrary partition.  You should be able to construct your graphs from this.

By the way, if you are really just focusing on connected components, you won't see any off diagonal connections, and this code can be simplified much more.  I'm assuming you meant partitions and subgraphs.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(n=40, p=0.05)
A = nx.to_numpy_matrix(graph)

cc_list = [list(cc) for cc in nx.connected_components(graph)]

def matrix_contraction(A, partition):
    contract_A = np.zeros((len(partition), len(partition)))

    for (ipart, ipartidx), (jpart, jpartidx) in combinations_with_replacement(enumerate(partition), 2):
        contract_A[ipart,jpart] = A[ipartidx][:, jpartidx].sum()
        contract_A[jpart,ipart] = A[jpartidx][:, ipartidx].sum()

    return contract_A


contracted_adj_matrix = matrix_contraction(A, cc_list)        




print(cc_list)
print(contracted_adj_matrix)
```

Comment: with 400 vertices partitioned into 50 parts, this working much slower than what I currently have. I only need a simple graph, could I make things faster by simply checking for existence of an edge rather than doing a sum?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve edited your code. Try if it’s faster:

```
import networkx as nx
import random

G = nx.random_tree(1000)

def sp(graph, percent_of_edges):
    """returns a subgraph with a certain percentage of edges"""
    out = nx.Graph()
    edges = graph.edges
    sample = random.sample(edges, k = int(len(edges) * percent_of_edges/100))
    out.add_edges_from(sample)
    return out

# Creating H from S
spr = sp(G, 80)
H = nx.Graph()
bound = []

CC = list(nx.connected_components(spr))
H.add_nodes_from(range(len(CC)))

for c in CC:
    bound.append(nx.node_boundary(G, c))

for num1, c in enumerate(CC):
    for num2, b in enumerate(bound):
        if c.intersection(b):
            H.add_edge(num1, num2)
```